# Known user in jetty login service

Tags: java, jetty

I am trying to change a program that it implements its login service from jetty login service. Whenever the URL is hit by a client a login page pops up.  However I am trying to check if the IP address of the client who has opened the page is known (logged in before, and I store the IPs of logged in users in a map ), do the login without asking for username and password. How can I set condition for login service provided by jetty?